# Splitting these string without clobbering split param's?

Tags: c#, .net

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to split a string while preserving line endings?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/492700/how-to-split-a-string-while-preserving-line-endings)
>   [How do I split a string by strings and include the delimiters using .NET?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2484919/how-do-i-split-a-string-by-strings-and-include-the-delimiters-using-net)

I'm splitting text into sentences. mystring.Split('.','!', '?') returns the sentences without the ./!/? on them. I need to have it return a sentence with the split param on the end? How does that go? Thanks

```
public static string[] GetSentences(string text)
{
    return text.Split('.', '!', '?'); 
}
```

I can think of one way to do it, by combining two separate arrays, but I think it looks awful so I thought I'd ask you professionals for a "proper" way :D

Edit - never mind close its a duplicate. I found the other threads, sorry

Comment: How about posting your solution?

Comment: Note that `.` doesn't always mean the end of a sentence. It can also occur in the middle of a sentence, for example after an abbreviation. You may want to consider using a natural language library if you want a more accurate result.

Answer (score 1):

Right, string.Split() isn't the right tool here.

Either simply loop through it (string.IndexOf())

or use a RegEx:  `([^\.!?]+[\.!?])*`

I'm not 100% sure about the escaping.